# Easier than Visual Basic 6?

Tags: vb6

Some years ago I used to program in VB6, I really liked it because it was very simply and fast, when VB.net came out, I abandoned it because they changed a lot of things.
I wonder if after all this years there's a new language or IDE that helps programming in an easier and faster way than VB6.
I'm not very interested in academic/personal issues like, very high performance, great movility through OSs, open source, etc. I would like to know if there's is something to program small and medium desktop apps. in an very easy and fast way.

Excuse me if my english isn't very clear.

Edit answering Nicholas:
Well, I must admit that I didn't try VB.Net too much, I was a little disappointed because I would had to learn a lot of new things and I've had learned VB6 not so long before (in that moment).

Comment: In addition to making it a community wiki, you might want to mark it as [subjective], also.  There's no right answer.

Comment: By 'easier and faster' what do you mean exactly?  IMHO it doesn't get much easier than Pseudocode!

Comment: To be honest, you should probably just go ahead and learn VB.NET. We're coming up on like 10 of .NET here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

VB.Net is the natural progression of VB6, and has a lot of free tools and resources online to get started. Microsoft even provides a free development environment as well as a free database for development/bundling in your applications.

Check out [this website](http://www.microsoft.com/Express/) for information and download links on all the free Microsoft software.

Also, you said you tried VB.Net and didn't like it-- I'd be curious to know why? Yes, there's a little learning curve, but the abundance of getting started information on the internet surely can help that. I was a bit overwhelmed by .NET at first (particularly ASP.Net) not seeing the value in switching/learning a new language.

Comment: I agree.  If you already know VB6, go this route.  It's different, but it will be very familiar to you.  Unless you just want to learn something completely different as a learning exercise...

Comment: I don't know if you are a professional programmer, business power user, or hobbyist, but IMHO, the learning curve from VB6 to .NET is a good investment in your skillset.  It's a strong platform that's not going away any time soon .. and like Nicholas said, now theres a free IDE.

Answer (score 8):

I always felt Microsoft Access was far and away the best for this kind of requirement.

edit - I realize this isn't a politically correct answer.  But the total package of a built in DB, a *great* GUI development package, a great report generator (far superior to crystal reports, for example), the easy development of tables and queries, all put in one friendly package, make it nearly trivial to develop with. For rapid development, it's the best I've used.

FWIW, I do Java, C++, C, VB4/6, ASP, JSP, Perl, PHP, CSS/ DHTML, JavaScript, Pascal, Fortran, Kenemy and Kurtz Basic, BAL, unix shell scripting, Oracle, mySql, RPG III, COBOL, some proprietary stuff, various macros, various distributed technology, Job control language, CPL, etc. etc. I got out of  developing in Access because of scalability limitations.

Comment: I'd certainly include it as a viable candidate for further discussion.

Comment: I'd also agree that MS Access can be used effectively as a front-end (to say a SQL backend). Like most things it cab be abused or used well.

Answer (score 5):

One of the easiest languages to learn and use is [Python](http://python.org/).

Comment: Absolutely. Most Python newbies who are not biased about the indentation of Python source code become Python fans :)

Comment: And some people prefer the indentation, since it's simple, obvious and generally done (informally) in many other languages.

Comment: Yay for Python in general, but it's not so simple for writing “small desktop apps” given that you have to choose a third-party GUI framework, which aren't generally *that* simple and don't have the Visual Studio-style UI builder integration a VB user might expect. (I hate those, but still.)

Comment: @AndrewHare: At least in the Python version I used, accidentally mistyping `SomeVariable = whatever` as `someVariable = whatever` would not result in any compiler diagnostic, but simply yield bogus code; the documentation didn't specify any way to disable implicit variable declarations.  Was that just a bad implementation or weak documentation?  I would find it very hard to take seriously any language which allows implicit variable declarations by default.

Answer (score 5):

[Powerbasic](http://www.powerbasic.com/) may be to your liking -

http://www.powerbasic.com/

Comment: Powerbasic in combo with FireFly (http://planetsquires.com) is pretty much unbeatable.

Answer (score 3):

Python or Ruby.

Dynamic languages has a number of advantages (and disadvantages) but for what you propose they seem perfect.
I would recommend python or ruby bindings of a high level toolkit as a perfect environment. For instance the Qt library gives most functionality you would need and dynamic languages let you easy experimentation

Answer (score 3):

FLEX / AS3 / MXML / AIR (tnx [le dorfier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/31641/le-dorfier)) comes very close to that VB6 feel from many years ago. But understands stuff like CSS and produces output that works in browsers on any platform (or desktop with AIR). You write code and run it, the coding cycle is very fast. And AS3 is at least as powerful as VB6 ever was, plus there are myriad add-ons and libraries to support all sorts of applications, all the major  web-services, database interface, animation, video, 3D, auto-generation of PHP code, etc.etc.etc...

And Flex Builder 3 is **free** for students and educators.

[alt text http://www.infoworld.com/infoworld/img/17TC-adobe-flex-builder.jpg](http://www.infoworld.com/infoworld/img/17TC-adobe-flex-builder.jpg)

Comment: Not sure why it was downvoted - a good answer. You might want to add AIR to cover the non-browser side.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has a new dialect of BASIC called [Small Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/cc950524.aspx).  From the website:

> Small Basic is ... a small and easy to learn
>   programming language in a friendly and
>   inviting development environment,
>   Small Basic makes programming a
>   breeze. ...
>
> Small Basic derives its inspiration
>   from the original BASIC programming
>   language, and is based on the
>   Microsoft .NET platform. It is really
>   small with just 15 keywords ...
>
> The Small Basic development
>   environment ...provides
>   powerful modern environment features
>   like Intellisense™ ...

Answer (score 2):

If it already wasn't done, I'd recommend Python. It's one of the easiest languages to learn.

My first language was Pascal and I think it's also one of the easiest languages and with Delphi getting popular again I think it's a very good alternative to VB6.

I've always found Delphi to be easier than VB despite popular belief.

Comment: Me too. I always had the feeling I could work more directly towards solving my problems, instead of forever trial and erroring.

Answer (score 2):

The first two versions of VB.NET had serious shortcomings compared to Visual Basic 6. However most of these issues has been fixed since Visual Studio 2005. Today, for new projects, I feel that everything that made VB6 so easy to use is available with VB.NET plus you get new language constructs, and the .NET framework. There also refactoring, and the VB Power Pak which brings back the older simple to use print engine.

Of course there is a learning curve involved. But no more than the leap from QuickBASIC/PDS to VB 1. If you have to maintain or transfer an older project then the differences between VB6 and VB.NET are much more serious.

Finally there is the Mono Project which support the VB compiler. This provides a degree of relative immunity from Microsoft deciding to break backwards again.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [Clarion](http://softvelocity.com/index.htm) is what you're looking for? Personally, I don't have much experience with it, but you can build some nice apps with virtually no coding skills.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [FreeBASIC](http://www.freebasic.net/).
It's syntax is *very* similar to that of VB and it is an actively worked on open-source project, it is also portable across different platforms.

You can grab a download [here](http://www.freebasic.net/index.php/download) and there are several exemplary works that can be found [here](http://www.freebasic.net/index.php/gallery).

Answer (score 1):

take a look at [Lua](http://lua.org)

- very small core language, the whole documentation is a single (very readable) webpage. you can easily learn the basics in a weekend.
- very good (small) books with good tips.
- very helpful community.
- very fast, both with the standard bytecode VM, and the JIT.
- used a lot in games, both because it's fast and easy to embed in the application, and because it's easy to explain to players interested in extending the game.
- readable sources.
- MIT license, use for whatever you like, no strings attached.

Answer (score 0):

I think C# is a very good language to program GUI apps quick and easy.

Answer (score 0):

While this might not be a complete answer to your question, I would recommend spending some time learning a more complex language (Objective-C, Java, C#, etc).  With the experience you learn with OOP design patters etc, in the future you won't have to shop around for the "easiest" language to program with.

Answer (score 0):

visual basic.NET is much more easier and have complete features than VB6 as I've experienced.

Answer (score 0):

I recently messed around with Microsoft Lightswitch and found it extremely VB like.  Very fast for binding to a database and generating forms, grids, etc.

Answer (score 0):

More than 10 years after this question was asked, the best answer is...

...to continue using the VB6 programming language.

VB6 still works on Windows 10 and Windows Server 2019. Just as it has since Windows 98.

Microsoft's support policy for VB6 is here [VB6 support policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/visual-basic-6-support-policy)